# How to mimic iOS Control Center behaviour

Tags: ios, controls, center, slide, behavior

I'd like to mimic the iOS Control Center behaviour. I have a button in the bottom of my screen, and I'd like to reveal a second view controller as the user slides from that button to the top.

The behaviour is also similiar to the iOS and the Android status bar. What's the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: you can do the same using "UIPresentationViewController"